# NSNumericSearch solution for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSString that I would like to search numerically.  It seems that NSNumericSearch would be the appropriate solution, but apparently only compare:, caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare: and localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: work as sort selectors when doing a fetch in iOS. (It's a core data project).  It is my understanding that this has something to do with the SQLite backing data store.

I have tried casting the string to an NSNumber.  There is an error with ARC, as NSNumber is basically an int.

In summary, I would like to sort a string numerically (1, 2, 11, 25) as opposed to (1, 11, 2, 25). I would appreciate any solutions.

.

.

EDIT: (I apologize for the above. I was away from my computer at the time, and in a hurry.)

The information about the limited sort descriptors comes from the last page of Isted & Harrington's 2011 book 'Core Data for iOS'.

> *When doing a fetch with sort descriptors you'll need to restrict yourself to the following selectors on iOS:
>   compare:,
>   caseInsensitiveCompare:,
>   localizedCompare:,
>   localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:*.

For clarification, I wrote a category like this:

```
@interface NSString (SizeComparison)
-(NSComparisonResult)sizeCompare:(NSString*)otherString;
@end
@implementation NSString (SizeComparison)
-(NSComparisonResult)sizeCompare:(NSString*)otherString {
return [self compare:otherString options:NSNumericSearch];
}
@end
```

The sort descriptor in fetchedResultsCntroller is as follows:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES selector:@selector(sizeCompare:)];
```

It returns this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: sizeCompare:'

This seems to be consistent with Isted & Harrington's statement.

Also, when I said that I casted to NSNumber, I was trying to be brief, but obviously was unclear. This is what I did:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numformatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
self.objectToEdit.size = [numformatter numberFromString:self.sizeTextField.text];
```

So, I would like to sort an NSString numerically (1, 2, 11, 25) as opposed to (1, 11, 2, 25). I would still appreciate any solutions.

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand. One time you say you have NSString, than you say you have core data. And your "in summary" says another thing. Please refine your question and provide some code snippets. It will increase greatly the chances to get an answer.

Comment: @Krizz You're right. It was a lousy post. I've tried to clarify.

Comment: @DavidDunham Poorly stated on my part.

Comment: `NSNumber` is an object and it has `compare:` which should return correct order as you desire. What is the problem you are getting when using `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the answer to the problem of sorting strings numerically.  It involves the use of a block directly.  For my sort descriptor it is simply:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"size" ascending:NO comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
```

This allows the NSStrings to be sorted numerically (1, 11, 2, 25).

I'm not sure why a category didn't work. Thought I would post answer for others that encounter the same issue.

Comment: This is lovely.  Thank you.  (Although blocks are from the devil.)

Answer (score 0):

> apparently only compare:, caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare: and localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: work as sort selectors when doing a fetch in iOS

Really?  I would think the issue is more that the selector you use can only take one parameter (the other string to compare against) and you need to use `-compare:options:` to do a numeric comparison.

Try writing a category method to do the comparison e.g.

```
@interface NSString(NumericCompare)

-(NSComparisionResult) compareNumerically: (NSString*) anotherString;

@end

@implementation NSString(NumericCompare)

-(NSComparisionResult) compareNumerically: (NSString*) anotherString
{
    return [self compare: anotherString options: NSNumericSearch];
}
```

> I have tried casting the string to an NSNumber. There is an error with ARC, as NSNumber is basically an int.

You can't just cast an NSSstring to an NSNumber, you are only casting the pointer, not the object pointed to.  You can do this

```
NSNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithString: myStringValue];
```

`NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thank you JeremyP.  I appreciate your consideration. As you can see, I tried the category method nearly identical to yours. You can see the error message in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

If there is really a restriction (in fact, I use only `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` in my code), you should be able to use `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` and use NSNumericSearch in your block.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get done what I needed without NSNumericSearch.

I changed the core data structure, changing the 'size' attribute to Integer16 and changing the model class property 'size' from NSString to NSNumber, and did a lightweight migration.

Then I modified my existing code just a little using:

```
aString = [aNumber stringValue];
```

and

```
NSNumberFormatter *numformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numformatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
bNumber = [numformatter numberFromString:bString]
```

where appropriate to change NSString and NSNumber objects.

Now it sorts like I desire.

In summary, I avoided the whole issue of numerically sorting NSStrings by changing the data structure.

The sort descriptors were just the basic ones used in fetchedResultsController:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey1 ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor2, nil];
```

Thanks for everyone's input. Sorry for the trouble.